# Running php script "behid"

Tags: javascript, php

Hi i need running the php script without moving to the script page, in the background

I have to check if there is a code in the file txt and if so, overwrite it and save the file again.

I know little js but very poor php, I have this in my index.php

```
<?php

$array_php = [];
$array_php = file('data.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

?>
```

this is my code html in index.php

```
<div  class="validation" style="">
   <form id="form1" method="post" action="save.php">
     <span class="codestyle">Please enter CODE 1</span>
     <input type="text" id="code1" class="code1" name="code1" style="margin:0 20px;"><br>

     <span class="codestyle2" style="margin-top: 20px;">Please enter CODE 2</span>
     <input type="text" id="code2" class="code2" name="code2" style="margin:0 20px;"><br>
                                          
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-icon ml-0" value="Check You Codes" style="margin: 20px 0 20px 35px;padding: 10px; width: 200px;" onclick="compute()">
   </form>
</div>
```

next i have js code to check code

```
<script>

var tab = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $array_php) . '"]' ?>;
    
function compute() {

    
    var code1 = document.getElementById("code1").value;
    var code2 = document.getElementById("code2").value;
          
    var codebar = code1+','+code2
          
    for (i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        
                
        if (codebar == tab[i]) {
            
            tab[i] = tab[i]+'__code_used';


            return swal({
                      title: "Great!",
                      text: "This is the Oryginal Malay Tiger Product",
                      icon: "success",              
                    });
                                                    
        }   else {}
                                
        }           
        return swal({
                      title: "Error!",
                      text: "Verification Code was used more then once or doesn't exist in codebase. Please Send the photo and information to our mail.",
                      icon: "warning",              
                    });     
}

</script>
```

and i have this code to update text file,  i have this code in file save.php
but I don't want a redirect ??

```
//deleting code from file
        $find = $_POST['PromoCode'];  //'PromoCode'
        
        $array = [];
        $array = file('data.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        
        for( $i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++ ) {  
            if ($find == $array[$i]){
                $array[$i] = $array[$i] . '_code_used';
            } else {}
        }
        
        file_put_contents('data.txt', join(PHP_EOL, $array));
        ///////
```

some help ?

Comment: What you're looking for is called Ajax. It allows you to make requests in the background, without refreshing or redirecting from the page you're on. There are many good tutorials out there for it.

Comment: I think that here is place for some workers / queue. If backend receives file - it have to dispatch information about it and some worker could handle that rewrite. It is far away from PHP basics.